# Meteor: Global constant not getting picked up from app/lib/_constants.js

Tags: javascript, meteor, simple-schema

My app directory structure is:

```
App
├── client
├── lib
│   ├── _constants.js
│   ├── config
│   └── router
├── modules
│   ├── answers
│   └── questions
├── node_modules
│   └── bcrypt
├── public
│   └── imgs
├── server
│   ├── lib
│   ├── roles
│   └── startup
└── settings-example.json
```

In my `_constants.js`, I have defined some global variables, e.g. `Schemas = {}` which I intend to use in the `modules > module_name> lib > collections.js` or `modules > module_name> lib > methods.js`

But the global variables are not found in the modules' collections.js. Here's the error I get:

```
W20160323-21:38:58.977(-7)? (STDERR) ReferenceError: Schemas is not defined
W20160323-21:38:58.977(-7)? (STDERR)     at modules/answers/lib/collections.js:22:1
W20160323-21:38:58.977(-7)? (STDERR)     at modules/answers/lib/collections.js:89:1
```

By my understanding, the global variables in the `APP/lib/_constants.js` file should have been loaded before the deeper `modules/module_name/lib/collections.js` got loaded, right?

But that's obviously not happening. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the "file load order" section from [Structuring your application](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp):

> There are several load ordering rules. They are applied sequentially to all applicable files in the application, in the priority given below:
>
> 1. HTML template files are always loaded before everything else
> 2. Files beginning with main. are loaded last
> 3. Files inside any lib/ directory are loaded next
> 4. Files with deeper paths are loaded next
> 5. Files are then loaded in alphabetical order of the entire path

The way this is implemented, a deeply nested `lib` is loaded **before** a less deeply nested `lib`, which explains your problem. Here are some options:

1. Don't use `lib` in your deep paths. E.g. rename the path like `modules/questions/stuff/collections.js`.
2. Move your modules into packages.
3. Upgrade to meteor 1.3 (still pre-release as of this writing) and start using the explicit `export`/`import` module syntax.

Comment: I had indeed read that section (many times in fact), but I think I might have misunderstood this part: `(the load ordering rules) are applied *sequentially* to all applicable files`. Doesn't this mean that the APP/lib/ files are loaded first (rule 3), and then the deeper files from modules/lib/ are loaded (rule 4)? Or are rules 3 and 4 applied in combination or something?

Comment: IIRC the rules actually combine. If you use my first suggestion does it solve the problem?

Comment: Yup, it does. I renamed the modules/lib to "modules/both", and it seems to work. Will be testing it more thoroughly, but no errors for now :) Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem. I just ran a few tests and it looks like this approach does seem correct.